# Ajax request in Web Browser Control working incorectly

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, session

I have a MVC web site with a httpGet function that do this

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult doSomething()
    {
        if(Session[SessionName.count] == null) 
            Session[SessionName.count] = 0;

        Session[SessionName.count] += 1;
        return Json(Session[SessionName.count], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

in the site there is a javascript function do this

```
function testing(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("doSomething", "Test")",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

and finally in my web browser control

```
public void ShowCount() 
{
    browser.Document.InvokeScript("Testing");
}
```

everytime ShowCount() is call, the alert box in web browser control will always 1.

Comment: Check Session[SessionName.count] is null

Comment: What kind of data you've been sent to JsonResult controller? Alert box contains "1" for every script invoke indicating `Session[SessionName.count]` initially contains zero, you should include more info about ajax call and how data stored into session variable.

Comment: This is just a test function, if the session value is null, initialize it to 0, otherwise increment by 1.

Comment: Session[SessionName.count] += 1; sets SessionName.count to 1 if session value is null.

Comment: What is `SessionName`? Some class, an enum, ... ?

Comment: It is a class for const variable

Comment: but in web site, it can show correctly increment, only happen in web browser control